# Iconos dentro del header de un acordeon

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente header de un acordeón, y algunos iconos del div del col-3 tienen función, pero si los presiono, aparte de ejercer una función js asignada, también abren o cierran el acordeón. ¿cómo puedo evitar que el acordeon no ejecute su función?

```
<div class="accordion-header rounded-lg collapsed col-11" id="accord-6One" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse6One" aria-controls="collapse6One" aria-expanded="true" role="button">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-9">
   <span class="accordion-header-text" contenteditable style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="titulovideo">Lección </span>
 </div>
 <div class="col-3">
  <span class="accordion-header-indicator"></span>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-vimeo mr-10" id="iconvideo" style="color:silver"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-file" id="iconapunte" style="color:silver"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-question" id="iconpregunta" style="color:silver"></i>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-trash" style="color:red"></i>
  <span id="acceso" data-acceso="0">
   <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No olvides adjuntar un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_). De hecho, al ser código HTML + CSS, podés insertarlo como snippet en la pregunta (con el botón que indica `<>`).

Comment: Adjunta el código completo de Javascript, edita tu pregunta ya que no se comprende del todo tu problema, recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.